# logback.xml works find at the local environment, but doesn't work in real server

Tags: java, scala, war, logback, scalatra

I'm using scala-based scalatra for web frameworks and I'm having trouble setting up logback.xml.

I set my logback.xml file in PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/logback.xml like below

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>server_error.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

and I set javaOptions variable in build.sbt file like below

**build.sbt**

```
settings = ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings ++ scalateSettings ++ Seq(
    organization := Organization,
    name := Name,
    version := Version,
    scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
    fork := true,
    javaOptions := Seq("-Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback.xml"),
    resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.5" % "runtime",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.15.v20160210" % "container",
      "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided",
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
      "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.11.142",
      "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"
    )
```

Logging process works really fine when I run this project on local environment, but from production server I cannot find "server_error.log" file from anywhere that should be generated by logback.xml. I'm using aws elasticbeanstalk and deployed on elasticbeanstalk the .war file generated by using 'package' command from sbt.

Comment: try change file path to  ${catalina.base}/logs/server_error.log  - log files willl be in tomcat in logs folder

Comment: You try put logs in PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/logback.xml. Localy is possible, because you have this location. After export to .war this location is in zipped file, so you can not put there any file. You must change path to log files, which you have on your production server.

Comment: I changed log file path to ${catalina.base}/server_eror.log and changed logback.xml location to /WEB-INF/logback.xml and also -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml but it's still not working...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar problem